# How to get php variable before included file

Tags: php, html

I have a template which uses a php include file $content to display the main contents of the page. I want to have the page title change depending on the content. I can declare $pagetitle in the included $content php file but the problem is that in the layout the content is loaded after the pagetitle.

I don't want to have to set $pagetitle from my code every time I load a page, I'd rather have it in the relevant content file so it sets automatically every time I include the page. How can I do this?

```
    <div class="container">
        <main class="content">
           <div id="ctopspace"><h2><?php echo $pagetitle;></h2></div>
             <div id="cleftspace"></div>             
             <?php  include $content;?>
        </main><!-- .content -->
    </div><!-- .container-->
```

Comment: Move your whole `.content` class to the `$content` include?

Comment: You could use $_GET to find out your current location. This is assuming you're using some kind of routing system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your file above all other code and `echo` the respective content and title variables after you did a

```
$content = file_get_contents( your_content_file );
```

in your included file.

```
<?php include $contentFile ?>

//...later in the code

<h2><?= $pagetitle; ?></h2>
<div id="cleftspace"></div>             
<?=  $content; ?>
```

Note: The `<?=` is an *open short tag* for `<?php echo`. It may be disabled on your server.

Comment: Thanks I'm not sure I fully understand. $content in my code refers to a php file with html in it. If I include that above my code it will output html in the wrong place.

Comment: No. ( Thanks for commenting. ) You should only save the whole php file in a variable and output it where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
file_put_contents('page-title.txt', $pagetitle);
```

and in the $content file

```
<h2><?php echo @file_get_contents('page-title.txt'); ?></h2>
```

ps: @ is just to skip `file_exists` step )